# SUBSTITUTE formula to separate hours and minute by comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have formula to separate hours and minutes by comma.

```
=CEILING(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(P96;"s";"");" min";"");" hour ";",");0,1)
```

This works for `4 hours 40 mins` and `1 hour 10 mins`. However there might case like `20 mins`. Then my formula is displaying 20 that is not correct and should be 0,2. Any suggestions how to fix this issue?

**Note!** Values like `4 hours 40 mins` are in one cell, in this case in cell P96. Information comes straight from Google Maps xml.

Comment: I would control each part using iferror, so if the hours are zero then blank or ignore, same for minutes etc But have you looked at custom formats?

Comment: what would be the expected output of `4 hours 40 mins`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionally add a dummy prefix that satisfies the *hours* substitution.

```
=CEILING(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("hour"; P96)); "0 hours "; "")&P96;"s";"");" min";"");" hour ";",");0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=CEILING(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("hour";P96));SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(P96;"s";"");" min";"");" hour ";",");"0,"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(P96;"s";"");" min";""));0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Type your time in cell A1. As an example, you could type "2:30", "14:30" or "2:30 PM".
2. Type "=HOUR(A1)" in cell A2 to produce only the hour. As an example, extracting the hour "2:30 PM" would give you "14," because 2 PM is the fourteenth hour in the day.
3. Type "=MINUTE(A1)" in cell A3 to extract the minutes.
4. Type "=SECOND(A1)" in cell A4 to extract the seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This would be easy, but I can't just type. This inforamtion comes from Google Maps xml, so Google provides it as it is.